# In web app, make phonecall then go back to window after call ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, web-applications

I have the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var numCalled = jQuery('#NUMCALLED').val();
    if(numCalled !== "") {
        jQuery('#CALLSTART').val(new Date());
        window.location.href="tel://"+numCalled;
    }
})
```

...that, as intended, when the app loads (when running on a mobile phone), will take the current time and dump it into CALLSTART, then make a phone call.

The problem: Once that phonecall ends, it doesn't go back to the app page. Pressing the 'back' button makes it go back to the webpage *before* reaching this page that makes the call.

How can I make it stop going back too far? Do I need to make it call a dummy page that then makes the call, so that pressing the back button skips the dummy page and returns to the page I want? Would doing that even preserve the CALLSTART value?

There must be a better way to do this...?

Answer (score 0):

I found an approach that, while not ideal (it brings a popup that needs to be allowed by the user), is still an improvement:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var numCalled = jQuery('#NUMCALLED').val();
    if(numCalled !== "") {
        jQuery('#CALLSTART').val(new Date());
        window.open("tel://"+numCalled,'_blank');
    }
})
```